# Outlook REST API: How to page through $search results, when searching for messages

Tags: outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I have troubles paging through message search results with the rest API.
I have a request looking like this:

outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?$search="deni"

the request returns a proper result and also includes a 'next page' looking like this:

"@odata.nextLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?%24search=%22deni%22&%24top=10&%24skiptoken=aT01NjMzYWQ3OS02MmJjLTQ5ZDEtODg4ZC0zYTgwNDlhOTY3Nzkmcz0xMA%3d%3d"

I guess this link is URL encoded so I URL decode it to get this:

outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?$search="deni"&$top=10&$skiptoken=aT01NjMzYWQ3OS02MmJjLTQ5ZDEtODg4ZC0zYTgwNDlhOTY3Nzkmcz0xMA==

However, when i try to make request with the next link I'm getting 405 Method Not Allowed with the following error:

"The OData request is not supported."

I've tried it in the sandbox as well (oauthplay.azurewebsites.net) - same result. What could it be that I am doing wrong. What is the right way to page through the search results?

I know that there is a limit of 250 messages that could be searched, but this is not the case here. I have 10 and I am trying to read the next 10.
Of course I have tried paging with the $skip and $top parameters, but $kip is not supported together with $search.
I can't seem to find a definitive answer in the documentation on how to page through search results and is it possible at all.

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

Comment: hi! Did you find solution?

Comment: no, no answer so far and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this now

Comment: in our case, message is starting with: `<span style="display:none"><?= $uuid ?>-<?= $timestamp ?></span>`, and all search requests goes through microsoft graph and it works perfectly.

Comment: decoding the URL and then sending the request is working